# How to install 3rd party applications using Electron as a background process

Tags: electron, electron-builder

How can I automate the process of installing a 3rd party software installation along with my electron app installation. Is that possible?

#### Usage scenario.

I want to make an application which deals with github repositories, now I want my users to install my app. In the same time I would like to install `git` for them. As a background process.

NOTE: I want to automate the process for all the Operating Systems. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible, but there isn't going to be an off-the-shelf way to install git on any platform.

I looked at [git-it-electron](https://github.com/jlord/git-it-electron) and they ask that you install Github Desktop first.

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is closed source but they don't require you to install git first as they use [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/) to interact with repositories. Is that an option for you?